# compare two arrays and check the check box if value present in array2

Tags: javascript

I have two arrays called array1 and array2.

I want to compare both and want to check the checkbox if value present in array2.

ex :

```
array1.compare(array2){
    <input type="checkbox" id="myCheckbox" checked="checked" />
}
```

Please help me and Thanks in Advance.

Comment: Please provide more details about your question. What do the arrays contain, what are you using for comparison, how do you want to check if the checkbox is in the array, etc

Comment: array will contains strings like array1[stringa,stringb,stringc,stringd] array2 [stringd,stringe,stringe] ...I am using === operator to compare both arrays...i want to create a checkbox and i want to check the checkbox if the values of array1 is present in array2..here its 'stringd'...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The question I believe should have been:

*I have two arrays, array1 and array2. If all the elements of array1 are present in array2, the checkbox with the id "myCheckbox" should become checked.*

If I'm right, here's my solution:

```
// Assume initially that all elements from array1 are in array2 
var shouldCheck = true; 
// Check initial assumption
for (var i in array1) { 
    // Assume the current element from array1 is not in array2
    var found = false; 
    for (var j in array2) { 
        // Element found
        if (array1[i]===array2[j]) { 
            found = true; 
        } 
    }  
    // Assumption was proven false
    if (!found) { 
        shouldCheck = false; 
    }
} 
// Check / uncheck the checkbox, according to outcome
document.getElementById("myCheckbox").checked = shouldCheck;
```